# Wait for a URL to download all the contents of a webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, settimeout, wait

I have to download HTML Content of a URL. The problem is that the URL takes some time to load , so I have to wait/ timeout for sometime ( ~10 - 15 secs) before logging the content. To achieve this, I tried 2 approaches, but all of them fail to produce the desired result.

First approach is the use of setTimeOut:

```
var page = require('webpage').create()
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 10000);  
    }
});
```

But setTimeout fails to set the specified timeout. No matter what value I put as Timeout , it times out after a fixed amount of time which is less than the page load time.

The second approach was the use of OnLoadFinished:

```
var page = new WebPage(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    console.log("load finished");
};

var steps = [
    function() {
        page.open("url");
    },

    function() {
        console.log(page.content);
    }
];


interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
        console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
        steps[testindex]();
        testindex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
        console.log("test complete!");
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 5000);
```

In this approach, OnLoadFinished fires before the full page is loaded.

I am new to phantomJS , so the above two solutions are also from stack overflow. Is there something I am missing that is particular to my case ? Is there any other way to achieve the same result? ( I tried [Waitfor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) construct also, but with no success).

Comment: `page.open(url, loadFunction)` and `page.onLoadFinished = loadFunction; page.open(url);` are equivalent

Comment: It seems that you have a page that is populated dynamically. You haven't actually defined in what way the page is different from what you expect. Is the content empty? Have you tried to take a screenshot (`page.render`)? Your first snippet is correct. Maybe you have page errors and regardless of the amount of time you wait, the page won't change ...

Comment: please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I took a screenshot, the final output is a 28 page report , but I am able to download only first 2 pages of that report. So, maybe waiting ( setting Timeout ) for some time will do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you problem is to load Content after some timeout. If you are looking for DOM element, you have to use known to you `WaitFor` function. But if you just want to get page content after timeout, it is so much easier. So lets start.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var address = "http://someadress.com/somepath/somearticle";
var timeout = 10*1000;

page.open(address);


function getContent() {
    return page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.body.innerHTML;
    });
}

page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(getContent());
    }, timeout);

}
```

**Note!** If you are waiting for large content in HTML body, use setInterval function, to wait for `document.body.innerHTML` more than you want.

Comment: Can't we wait for more than 10s in setTimeOut? I tried setting timeout to 15 , 18 secs , but in that case it did not download anything. And how can SetInterval() construct be used , in case we want to wait more? Thanks.

Comment: I took a screenshot, the final output is a 28 page report , but I am able to download only first 2 pages of that report